# How to know what is being written in Python during import module?

Tags: python, pandas, cuda, theano, keras

It is very strange on one of my Ubuntu when I import modules, for one module the pandas, it will take random time (from 0.9 to 160s ) to completed. 
[image: Import pandas in 161s]

I am not sure what cause the problem, but I found that during module loading python is writing something to the Disk with IOW/s= 2M .

So my question is:

**Is there a way to track which file Python is writing to during execution?**

Python 2.7 , Cuda 8.0 RC , cuDnn 5.1,  Theano 9.0-dev, keras , pandas 0.18.1

---

After tracking I found python is writing to the /home/username/.nv/ComputeCache  ,  so maybe one of the GPU related libs cause this problem. But I have no idea why only pandas is affected .

---

Thanks all, I find a workaround: import pandas first.

Comment: Maybe you can specifically put here your code that shows the import? Because you suddenly mention "model loading" and "Theano" and "Keras" towards the end, which suggest that your problem might be more specific to your specific code, and not the general "during import module" as the question title suggests.

Comment: @justhalf thanks for point that out, I do have a small script for testing the "import" and I cant reproduce my problem.  But this problem appears all the time (not test what happen after a reboot ) when I run my program so that I want to know what is being written.

Comment: I see. Then if you really want to check what's being written and you think that's useful for future references also, I guess you should rephrase the question to focus on that part, and not the random time of your loading. Also, the question in the body can be updated to something like "So is there a way to track which file Python is writing to during execution?" to be more general. (currently you have "during model loading" which is not relevant to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `strace` to trace system calls.

```
$ strace -ttt -feopen,write -o log python -c 'open("foo", "w").write("blah")'
$ cat log
...
122157 1468546777.800508 open("foo", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, 0666) = 3
122157 1468546777.800733 write(3, "blah", 4) = 4
122157 1468546777.804145 +++ exited with 0 +++
```

This should show what files are being opened and written to, and the time of each event.

Comment: Thanks, after tracking I found python is writing to the /home/username/.nv/ComputeCache  ,  so maybe one of the GPU related libs cause this problem.

Comment: You can prevent that by doing `os.environ['CUDA_CACHE_DISABLE']='1'` before importing your GPU libs. More details here: http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#env-vars